# Can't update fields from db

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to update some fileds in the database using a form and for some reason it just refreshes the page without doing anything. Here's the code I used:

```
<?php 

$id = $_GET["id"];
$select = "SELECT * FROM blog_members WHERE memberID = '$id'";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $select);
$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$id2=$row['memberID'];
$username=$row['username'];
$password = $row['password'];
$email = $row['email'];
?>

<form id="form" action="#" method="post">
<br><table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
<tr><td>Username:</td>
<td><input name="username" type="text" id="username" placeholder="<?php echo $username; ?>" size="25" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Password:</td>
<td><input name="password" type="text" id="password" placeholder="<?php echo $password; ?>" size="25" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Email:</td>
<td><input name="email" type="text" id="email" placeholder="<?php echo $email; ?>" size="25" /></td></tr>
</table>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="Edit" value="Save" />
</center></form>

<?php 

if(isset($POST['Edit'])){
$username2 = $_POST['username'];
$password2 = $_POST['password'];
$email2 = $_POST['email'];

$edit = mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE blog_members SET username='$username2',password='$password2',email='$email2' WHERE memberID='$id2'");
$result1 = mysqli_query($link,$edit);

if(!$result){
 echo mysqli_error($link);
}else{
echo "Changes have been saved successfully!";
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"2;URL=view-users.php\">";
}

}
?>
```

I think the query $edit it's not working properly since the page just gets refreshed and the fields from the databse are not updated. I feel like I'm missing something. Any suggestions?

Comment: why two time update query?

Comment: there are no action in the form?

Comment: May be the id is reset after submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also change below code

```
if(isset($POST['Edit'])){
```

with this, `$_POST` is right syntax not `$POST`

```
if(isset($_POST['Edit'])){
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew I missed something but I couldn't tell what.

Answer (score 0):

I got two things..

1. You lost the `ID` that is gets `$id = $_GET["id"];`.
2. Mysql Update Query two times.

**Solution:**
Post your id in the form and get the posted id and use it to update and use a single query to update.

**Updates:** I miss the main point and that is `$POST`, you need to change the `if(isset($POST['Edit']))` to `if(isset($_POST['Edit']))`.

Let me know, if you need more support from me.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I figure it out. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try This..

```
<input name="username" type="text" id="username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>" size="25" />
<input name="password" type="text" id="username" value="<?php echo $password; ?>" size="25" />
<input name="email" type="text" id="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?> " size="25" />
```